# AJV - Help understand strictmode warnings

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I have the following json schema:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Form Field configuration",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The field label"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The field description"
    },
    "presentation": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Configuration for the field visual UI",
      "properties": {
        "inputType": {
          "title": "The recommend way to represent the field visually.",
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "const": "text",
              "title": "Similar to the HTML `<input>` with text type."
            },
            {
              "const": "number",
              "title": "Similar to the HTML `<input>` with number type."
            },
            {
              "const": "money",
              "title": "Similar to 'number', dedicated to monetary values."
            }
          ]
        },
        "currency": {
          "title": "For inputType=money. Monetary Currency Code (3 digits)",
          "maxLength": 3,
          "minLength": 3,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The field description with HTML"
        }
      }
    },
    "$template": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Pass the template URL to a given field"
    }
  },
  "required": ["presentation"],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$comment": "Extend the base Draft-07 configuration",
      "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"
    },
    {
      "$comment": "Add presentation validations only when $template is not present.",
      "if": { "required": ["$template"] },
      "else": {
        "properties": {
          "presentation": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/presentation_validations"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "$comment": "If it contains presentation.description, then [root].description is also required.",
        "properties": {
          "presentation": {
            "required": ["description"]
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": ["description"]
      }
    }
  ],
  "$defs": {
    "presentation_validations": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "required": ["inputType"]
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "inputType": { "const": "money" }
            },
            "required": ["inputType"]
          },
          "then": {
            "required": ["currency"]
          },
          "else": {
            "properties": { "currency": false }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I log the strict mode warnings, I get the following warnings:

```
strict mode: required property "$template" is not defined at "#/allOf/1/if" (strictRequired) 

strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "required" at "#/$defs/presentation_validations/allOf/0" (strictTypes) 

strict mode: required property "inputType" is not defined at "#/$defs/presentation_validations/allOf/0" (strictRequired) 

strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "required" at "#/$defs/presentation_validations/allOf/1/if" (strictTypes) 

strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "#/$defs/presentation_validations/allOf/1/if" (strictTypes) 

strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "required" at "#/$defs/presentation_validations/allOf/1/then" (strictTypes) 

strict mode: required property "currency" is not defined at "#/$defs/presentation_validations/allOf/1/then" (strictRequired) 

strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "properties" at "#/$defs/presentation_validations/allOf/1/else" (strictTypes) 

strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "required" at "#/allOf/2/if/properties/presentation" (strictTypes) 

strict mode: required property "description" is not defined at "#/allOf/2/if/properties/presentation" (strictRequired) 

strict mode: required property "description" is not defined at "#/allOf/2/then" (strictRequired)
```

But I don't understand what do I need to change and, most importantly, when I need to do them, as if I validate against some jsons, they work as expected.

Here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ajv-strict-mode-warnings-b88re5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJV's "strict mode" prevents you from making common mistakes which could lead to creating a JSON Schema which is less specified (or "more underspecified") than you expect.

Let's take the first error you see.

> strict mode: missing type "object" for keyword "required" at "#/allOf/1/if/properties/presentation" (strictTypes)

The `required` keyword [only applies to objects](https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/applicability-json-schema-fundamentals-part-1#validating-objects). This means if the instance data at that location was of another type, say, a string, then validation would pass. The `required` keyword doesn't mean it has to be an object. If you want it to be an object, you need to additionally specify such using the `type` keyword.

AJV's strict mode rule "strictTypes" explicitly requires that you specify the types if you use keywords which are only applied based on their type.

Consider a JSON Schema such as `{ "required": "name" }`. If the instance was an object, "name" would be required. However, if the instance data was in stead an array `[]`, it would also pass validation for the given schema in this example.

Comment: I personally take issue with AJV's strict mode, however I understand it's value in the absense of a linter.

Comment: Strict mode should not be on by default. It causes a lot of confusion to newbies, generates a lot of needless questions on stackoverflow and slack (like this one), and is in violation of the specification to boot.

Comment: Thank you @Relequestual for the explanation. I understand that `required` is only for objects. However, in my case, the required is applied to an object. (I think so) on line 16 with `"type": "object"`. So what am I missing here to fix the warning? 

P.S. I've updated both the schema example and codesandbox to better mimic my real schema. (added a "$template" property and "allOf".

Comment: @Ether no question is a needless question when a newbie is in their journey to learn a new vocabulary like JSON Schema.

Comment: I agree, but it doens't consider other schema locations targeting the same instance location, it only considers the same schema object. It's limited to basic use cases.

Comment: @sandrina-p it's not your fault; you're dealing with a tool that isn't doing things properly. If it was, you wouldn't be having this problem and having to ask this question.

Comment: I see. So, it means these warnings are a "bug/limitation" from the tool, not an issue on my schema, right? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @relequestual. There is a built-in linter/analyzer in [JSONBuddy](https://json-buddy.com) and it shows a major issue in your schema immediately:

[image: JSONBuddy JSON Schema linter results]

There is a `$ref` at the same schema as other keywords. Prior to draft 2019-09 all of the keywords next to `$ref` at the same level are **ignored** during validation.

AJV does not complain as you are using draft 7? Is this also present in your copy?

Often, a possible solution for an error like this is to use `allOf` and wrap the $ref and all other definitions in two separate (sub)schemas. Like:

```
"allOf": [
  { "$ref": "myref" },
  { ... all other definitions ... }
]
```

Comment: Oh, that would be great to use, but it seems JSONBuddy only works on Windows. I have MacOS. Do you know any other alternative?

Comment: Still regarding to that first $ref error, what's the fix for it?

Comment: I added a possible solution for the $ref problem.

Comment: at the same time you were answering, I also updated my schema example to better reflect my real schema. I guess it was already correct then by default, right? :)

Comment: It seems so. But I would have to adapt the syntax of your schema each time I try to analyze it in JSONBuddy because the editor requires the standard JSON notation using quotes.

Comment: I see. Let me update it to be proper json and I'll let you know when it's done.

Comment: both question and codesandbox updated. The schema is now a proper JSON file :)

Comment: Thx. Basically, JSONBuddy gives the same warnings as AJV with required properties like "description" not defined. But keep in mind, this is "just" a warning. It is totally fine in JSON Schema if you want to have a property required but you also don't want to define it in more detail. But you should provide test data where the property is sometimes present, and sometimes it isn't.